# How to install amazon prime video as an app in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: amazon

I want to install amazon prime video as an app because when I run prime video on browser video lag and run on sd and yes i also try edge browser it didn't work so please help me and tell how to install prime video as an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `Electron Player` from the ubuntu software center.

[image]

This supports (amongst others) Amazon Prime Video.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Prime Video is no longer supported.